# Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding in C# .Net RSA app

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I created this C# .Net Framework 4.7 console app to test Encrypt and Decrypt a text file using RSA. I have created one key pair and exported them to xml files and then they were imported to decrypt the file
But why does this gives a padding error?

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.'

This is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Generate a new RSA key pair
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

    // Export the public key to an XML file
    string publicKeyXml = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
    File.WriteAllText("public_key.xml", publicKeyXml);

    // Export the private key to an XML file
    string privateKeyXml = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
    File.WriteAllText("private_key.xml", privateKeyXml);


    // Encrypt the contents of the input file
    string inputFileName = "input.txt";
    string outputFileName = "output.txt";
    byte[] inputBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFileName);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(inputBytes, true);
    File.WriteAllBytes(outputFileName, encryptedBytes);

    // Load the RSA public key from an XML file
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    string publicKeyXml1 = File.ReadAllText("public_key.xml");
    rsa.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml1);

    // Load the RSA private key from an XML file
    string privateKeyXml1 = File.ReadAllText("private_key.xml");
    rsa.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml1);

    // Decrypt the contents of the output file
    byte[] read = File.ReadAllBytes("output.txt");
    byte[] decryptedBytes = rsa1.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, true);
    string decryptedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
    Console.WriteLine(decryptedText);
}
```

I tried changing the padding mode to PKCS#1 v1.5 but still the error persists.

Comment: Apply `rsa1.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml1)` for decryption (with `rsa1` instead of `rsa`). BTW, the public key does not need to be loaded for decryption. Also, it's probably supposed to be `rsa1.Decrypt(read, true)` (with `read` instead of `encryptedBytes`).

Answer (score 0):

Anyway i found a solution [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/rsaencryptionpaddingoaepsha256). Solution is that I had to replace RSACryptoServiceProvider with RSACng. Now it works fine.

edit---
As [Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco) mentioned it had mistakenly used rsa insted of rsa1. That method also works.

Comment: The answer does not solve the problem posted in the question. If you apply `RSACng` instead of `RSACryptoServiceProvider` in the above code, the problem still occurs. This is because the issue is not caused by `RSACryptoServiceProvider` itself, but by an incorrect key import: with `rsa1.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml1)` the code works (while you incorrectly use `rsa` instead of `rsa1`).